# Getting a value of a column in postput from the put

Tags: hbase

I am implementing a potput function in hbase, I need to get the value of special column in that

```
class AccessControlCoprocessor extends BaseRegionObserver {


@Override
public void postPut(ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> e,
                    Put put,
                    WALEdit edit,
                    Durability durability)
        throws IOException
{

/*
the original put was added in this way
    val p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(data.hashCode().toString()))


        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"),
          Bytes.toBytes("count"), Bytes.toBytes("1"))
I nee to get "1" from the above
*/

}
}
```

How to get "1" from the above , I want to do that using row key and columns identifier..

Answer (score 0):

When you know the column family, you can get the values directly from the `Put` object being passed into the coprocessor:

```
final List<Cell> cells = put.get(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("count"));

// we assume that there is only one cell in this Put transaction
Cell cell = cells.get(0)
byte[] value = CellUtil.cloneValue(cell);
String valueAsString = new String(value);
```

`CellUtils` is available from [`org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellUtil`](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/CellUtil.html)